# Drizzle npm install error with node scrypt@6.0.3 install and node-gyp rebuild

Tags: npm-install, drizzle

When you try to install drizzle:

```
npm install drizzle
```

it fails when node version mismatches and there are some unresolved lib dependencies with errors:

> In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_async.h:28:
>   ../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_common.h:39:63: error: too few
>   arguments to
>         function call, single argument 'context' was not specified
>         N(obj->Get(Nan::New("N").ToLocalChecked())->Uint32Value()),

Update: find answer below for correct way to install drizzle

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to install Drizzle is:

```
npm install @drizzle/store
```